# Quick check re subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, vector-spaces

Following my previous question (not necessary to refer to), let the number of automorphisms of an $n$-dimensional vector space be $k$. Then am I right in thinking that the number of $m$-dimensional subspaces is simply ${n\choose m}k$? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously false: take $m=n$.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, taking $m=n$ gives $k$ again, which was posited to be the number of automorphisms of the $n$-dimensional subspace; this would not be a counter-example.  However, taking $m=0$....

Comment: @Shaun: an $n$-dimensional space has precisely one $n$-dimensional subspace.